# Soap API invoke from java struts application java version 1.5 code

Tags: soap

Please help me sample code for invoke soap API in our web application that is developed in java 1.5 version with oc4j server.

required sample code for invoke soap API in our web application that runs in jdk 1.5 version.

i want to consume public exposed soap API into our code that is developed in 1.5 java version